# Opera: trouble with adding 'list' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

Today I've decided to add html5 datalist to certain input via user script. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwHFV/1/) the code. The problem is that `list` attribute isn't added. If I change it to anything different from `list`, like `lst` - it's there.

Is that supposed to be so? Is such behaviour set by specification or by browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I did some research on this.

[Spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#common-input-element-apis) that `input.list` returns related datalist object, not the attribute value. So you should use `setAttribute('list','edit-subject-themes')` on input, which [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Klaster_1/ZwHFV/3/). Seems like it was jQuery issue.

With problem solved, I'll sure use that technique in user JavaScript a lot :)